# Which proof is correct - strong induction - analysis 1 Tao

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, induction

I am studying analysis 1 by Tao. And i am trying to prove strong induction.

> **Strong induction:** Let $m_0$ be a natural number,and let $P(m)$ be a property pertaining to an arbitrary natural number $m$. Suppose that for each $m≥m_0$, we have the following implication: if $P(m')$ is true for all natural numbers $m_0≤m'<m$, then $P(m)$ is also true.(In particular, this means that $P(m_0)$ is true, since in the case the hypothesis is vacuous.) Then we can conclude that $P(m)$ is true for all natural numbers $m≥m_0$.

**Proof:1:** Assume to the contrary that $P(m)$ is not true for some $m ∈ ℕ $. Let $n$ be the least natural number s.t $P(n)$ is not true. If $m≤m_0$ , then the hypothesis, for all $m'$ s.t $m_0≤m'<m$ implies  $P(m')$  is vacuous. Thus $P(m_0)$ must be true for all $m≤m_0$. So we have $n>m_0$. By assumption $P(m')$ ka true for all $m'$ s.t $m_0≤m'<n$, thus we deduce that $P(n)$ is true. A contradiction.

**Proof:2:** We use induction on $m$.
Base case: If $m=m_0$, then $P(m_0)$ is true, since hypothesis is vacuous.
Inductive case: Assume inductively that the statement is true for some $k≥m_0$, i.e. for all $m'$ s.t $m_0≤m'<k$ implies $P(m')$ thus we have $P(k)$. We shall show statement is true for $S(k)$. By inductive hypothesis we see for all $m'$, $m_0≤m'≤k<S(k)$ we have $P(m')$ which implies $P(S(k))$, by assumption, as desired. This closes the induction.

> $S(k)$ denotes successor of $k$.

**Question**:
(1) Are both proofs correct? If not, then please mention.

(2)In the book Tao gives hint "define  $Q(n)$ to be the property that $P(m)$ is true for all $m_0≤m<n$". Did author give the hint because to not get confused in wording?

(3) I don't know why i feel less confident about my proofs. I feel both are incomplete and not rigours proofs. Is it common to feel like this?
Thank You.

Comment: In Proof 1, the assumption of the proof by contradiction should be "Assume that $P(m)$ is not true for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m\geq m_0$". The statement of Strong Induction doesn't prevent $P(m)$ being false for some $m<m_0$.

Comment: Proof 2 is not well written either. At least the step from assuming $P(k)$ to deducing that $P(m')$ is true for all $m_0\leq m'<k$ is not justified. This step is pretty much the whole story.

Comment: @NDB So there is no need to show that $P(m)$ is true for $m≤m_0$?

Comment: @NDB Can you please give me hint or correct solution?

Comment: I suppose that the book intents for you to prove Strong induction from induction. In Proof 1, you would need to prove that that "least natural number $n$" exists. The hint of using the proposition $Q$ is for you to apply induction on it. The application of induction for $Q$ is more of less direct.

Comment: Check $Q(m_0)$. As you mentioned, the statement "If $m_0\leq m'<m_0$" is vacuous. Therefore, the Strong induction assumption asserts that $P(m_0)$. Therefore, $Q(m_0)$ is true.

Comment: The inductive step for $Q$ would be to assume $Q(m)$ and deduce $Q(n+1)$. But if $Q(n)$, then for all $m'$ such that $m_0\leq m'<n$ we have $P(m')$. Then the strong induction assumption holds and it implies $P(n)$. But then it is true that for all $m'$ in $m_0\leq m'<n+1$ we have $P(m')$, which is the statement $Q(n+1)$.

Comment: @NDB I have abit confusion in base case."If $m_0≤m'<m_0$ is vacuous, then the implication $ ∀m'(m_0≤m'<m_0 \implies P(m'))$ is vacuously true. Thus $Q(m_0)$ is true. But why you mentioned $P(m_0)$ is true therefore $Q(m_0)$ is true?